# How to import and use packages in JSP

Tags: jsp

I am new to Java and also for JSP. I am having the problem with assigning the "out" object to the method like this

```
<%!
    public void printMe(javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter out) throws java.io.IOException {
        out.println("Successfully printed");
    }
%>
```

So I can just simply invoke it with something like this in the scriptlet

```
<% printMe(); %>
```

I know that this is about to pass the "out" object which is in general, defined in the scope of the _jspservice() method to the outside method called "printMe()" declared manually with declaration tag in which the "out" object can not be directly accessed. So we make it available there.

However, I found that the "javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter" which is passed as the parameter to the manually declared method can be written in another way like this

```
public void printMe(JspWriter out) {}
```

but before that, there is the import directive

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
```

I think this just makes the code shorter as I no longer have to define the full "java.io.IOException". So I try doing this

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

public void printMe(JspWriter out) throws IOException {
   out.println("successfully printed!");
}
```

Now the code does not work but when I change the "JspWriter" back to "javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter". So this is working for me

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
public void printMe(javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter) throws IOException {
    out.println("successfully printed!");
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code or there are other packages I have to import to enable me to properly use just "JspWriter" instead of the full "javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter" statement

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Change the JSP tag to scriplets tag

```
<%!
    public void printMe(javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter out) throws java.io.IOException {
        out.println("Successfully printed");
    }
%>
```

To

```
<%
    public void printMe(javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter out) throws java.io.IOException {
        out.println("Successfully printed");
    }
%>
```

In scriplet tag you can use `out`,`session`,`request`,`response` directly